# What is actually platform object mean in html spec

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, webidl

Html spec defines several ways to define Realms in js code via these conceptions: **Entry**, **Incumbent**, **Current**, **Relevant**.

The last one is [specified by html spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-relevant-everything) in a special form:

> Every **platform object** has a relevant Realm, which is roughly the JavaScript realm in which it was created. When writing algorithms, the most prominent **platform object** whose relevant Realm might be important is the this value of the currently-running function object. In some cases, there can be other important relevant Realms, such as those of any arguments.

If we follow to the [link that relates to the definition](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-platform-object) on the **platform object** we will see the next:

> **Platform object**s are objects that implement an **interface**.

What does mean interface in that case? Sure, I am not silly I looked into interface definition:

> An **interface** is a definition (matching interface InterfaceRest) that declares some state and behavior that an object implementing that interface will expose.

From here we see that this is generic definition of the interface.

---

Also I found the following [example of the **platform objects**](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-objects):

> In a browser, for example, the **browser-implemented DOM objects (implementing interfaces such as Node and Document)** that provide access to a web page’s contents to ECMAScript running in the page would be platform objects. These objects might be exotic objects, implemented in a language like C++, or they might be native ECMAScript objects.

As specified above instances of interfaces Node or Document are platform objects. Are their constructor objects - platform objects?

Now I've gotten a bunch of questions:

- What does **platform object** mean in whatwg spec? (ecmascript doesn't define this term)
- Which examples of objects are examples of **platform objects** and which are not?
- I didn't see interfaces of ECMAScript parts in whatwg, does it mean that initially ecmascript constructors and their instances are **not platform objects**?

P.S Please don't mark as "Needs more focus", I know that I asked several question in one issue, but these are parts of one general question.

Comment: The first two questions are answered directly by the sections you quoted, no?